# I can't get date values using $_GET

Tags: 7, views

In my view, I have two filters: title (text box), and date (combobox); date has two values: year and month.

When I select the filters parameters in the view, and I click *search*, the filter values appears in the URL such as in `mysite/views-path?title_filter=aaa&date_filter[year][value]=2012&date_filter[month][value]=3`.

I used `$_GET` to get the value of the title filter, and it worked, but I can't get the date values using `print $_GET['date_filter[year][value]'];`.

Can anyone tell me how to get values like date using `$_GET`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in query strings get converted into actual PHP arrays when you use `$_GET`.

To get the value in your case you'd use something like:

```
print $_GET['date_filter']['year']['value'];
```

Comment: i tried what you told me but doesn't work.

Comment: It must be a problem with Views then; you can test the logic yourself by installing the devel module and going to http://mysite.com/devel/php?date_filter[year][value]=2012. Then put `print $_GET['date_filter']['year']['value'];` in the code textfield and press 'Execute'. You'll see the string '2012' printed in the messages area, which proves the above method works